# update in arch - cannot commit transaction

Tags: linux, updates, arch-linux

```
 unixodbc-2.3.1-1-i686   196.1K  209.8K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 apr-util-1.3.12-4-i686  164.0K  201.4K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 firefox-9.0.1-1-i686     12.1M  215.4K/s 00:00:57 [######################] 100%
 git-1.7.8.1-1-i686        2.3M  216.7K/s 00:00:11 [######################] 100%
 qt-4.8.0-2-i686          20.4M  211.5K/s 00:01:39 [######################] 100%
 gperf-3.0.4-4-i686       88.5K  155.0K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 qtwebkit-2.2.0-3-i686     6.5M  257.3K/s 00:00:26 [######################] 100%
 kdelibs-4.7.4-2-i686     11.4M  262.4K/s 00:00:44 [######################] 100%
 redland-1:1.0.15-2...   185.9K  168.1K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-common...    55.4M  259.2K/s 00:03:39 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-base-3...  1691.9K  257.5K/s 00:00:07 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-calc-3...     3.9M  231.9K/s 00:00:17 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-draw-3...     3.4K 1205.4K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    27.7K  134.0K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...   104.5K  183.0K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...     2.1M  249.1K/s 00:00:09 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...     7.4K  457.5K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    78.3K  162.8K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    29.3K  138.2K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...     8.0K   38.7M/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...   370.6K  194.7K/s 00:00:02 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...   181.4K  205.6K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...   287.7K  227.0K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...     2.1M  259.0K/s 00:00:08 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    84.1K  168.9K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...   656.9K  245.6K/s 00:00:03 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    77.5K  166.3K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    42.3K  100.3K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    36.2K  165.0K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...    51.2K  130.4K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-extens...   596.7K  228.5K/s 00:00:03 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-gnome-...   172.9K  198.0K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-impres...    98.2K  167.1K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-kde4-3...    47.6K  126.3K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-math-3...   270.1K  225.4K/s 00:00:01 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-sdk-3....     4.7M  253.9K/s 00:00:19 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-sdk-do...   737.7K  248.9K/s 00:00:03 [######################] 100%
 libreoffice-writer...     2.3M  259.4K/s 00:00:09 [######################] 100%
 pyqt-4.8.6-2-i686         2.2M  219.2K/s 00:00:10 [######################] 100%
 python2-pyqt-4.8.6...     2.0M  255.7K/s 00:00:08 [######################] 100%
 redland-storage-vi...    16.1K   82.1K/s 00:00:00 [######################] 100%
:: Retrieving packages from community...
 wine-1.3.35-3-i686       14.4M  247.8K/s 00:01:00 [######################] 100%
(89/89) checking package integrity                 [######################] 100%
(89/89) checking for file conflicts                [######################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
filesystem: /etc/mtab exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

> error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
>       filesystem: /etc/mtab exists in filesystem
>       Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

Any idea why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Arch Linux website](http://www.archlinux.org/) has a news item explaining this:

> #### [News: filesystem upgrade - manual intervention required](http://www.archlinux.org/news/filesystem-upgrade-manual-intervention-required/)
>
> *2011-12-20 - Tom Gundersen*
>
> When upgrading to `filesystem-2011.12` there will be a conflict with `/etc/mtab.`
>
> Install the package as follows:
>
> `pacman -S filesystem --force`
>
> It is strongly advised to avoid the `--force` or `-f` switch as it is not safe. However, in this particular case it is needed as deleting `/etc/mtab` manually would break pacman.
>
> The reason for the conflict is that the file used to be generated at boot and hence not owned by any package. Now it is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts` owned by `filesystem`. This change means that `initscripts` no longer requires write access to the rootfs (though other packages might).